# Whether to say “c’est drôle comment” or “c’est drôle comme”

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, pronoms-interrogatifs

> C’est drôle **comment** ces incidents se déroulent tous aujourd'hui !
>
> C’est drôle **comme** ces incidents se déroulent tous aujourd'hui !

I assume the first and second constructions correspond to "it's funny how ..." and "it's funny since/because ..." respectively. I wonder which is more commonly used?

English speakers would probably be tempted to choose the first construction  « c’est drôle comment/how », but I'm not sure if it is acceptable to use « comment » like this as a conjunction.

Comment: I've just found this [blog page](http://blogs.transparent.com/french/how-to-use-comme-and-comment/) with a good synthetic view of the uses of *comme* and *comment*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Comme* implique une comparaison, implicite ou explicite. On peut le remplacer par « la façon dont ». Ce n'est pas un mot interrogatif.<sup>1</sup>

*Comment* est un mot interrogatif. Ça veut dire « quelle est la façon/la manière ... »<sup>2</sup>

Dans ton exemple tu veux dire → *c'est drôle la façon dont ces incidents se déroulent tous aujourd'hui*, c'est à dire :

> C'est drôle comme ces incidents se déroulent tous aujourd'hui.

Par contre si on pose une question :

> Je voudrais savoir /je ne sais pas comment ces incidents surviennent tous aujourd'hui.

---

Notes:
Attention à la place de *tous* qui doit être après le verbe. Ou avant le nom (c'est drôle comme tous ces incidents arrivent tous aujourd'hui).
Possibilité de remplacer « se dérouler » par « avoir lieu », « survenir » ou « se produire ».

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Comme peut être [beaucoup d'autres choses](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/comme). La réponse à la question ne se veut pas un cours exhaustif sur comme.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Il est parfois difficile de voir que certaines phrase  sont des questions, voir [l'exemple du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/comment) (B. 2) *Un service parfait! Voilà comment je suis dressé !*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

'comment' peut être utilisé si on souhaite parler de la similitude du déroulement des incidents et dans ce cas tous devrait être placer avant 'ces incidents' :

> C’est drôle comment tous ces incidents se déroulent aujourd'hui !

Cela exprime ici que les incidents du jours se déroulent tous de façon étonnantes, cela suggère que les incidents sont habituels mais qu'aujourd'hui ils ont un déroulement particulier.

Si l'on souhaite parler de la coincidence que tous ces incidents surviennent aujourd'hui on utiliserait 'comme' et dans ce cas 'tous' se placerait après 'déroulent' :

> C’est drôle comme ces incidents se déroulent tous aujourd'hui !

Ici cela exprime une coincidence étonnante que ces incidents arrivent tous le même jour.

Answer (score 1):

Etonnement, il ne ressort pour l'instant pas des réponses données que l'utilisation du mot "comment" de telle sorte est ***probablement*** incorrecte.

Le terme "comment" doit pouvoir être substitué par "de quelle manière, par quels moyens". Or, dans cette phrase, il s'agit plus de qualifier de drôle la concomitance constatée, que de qualifier de drôle une quelconque interrogation quant au processus conduisant à cette concomitance.

Ainsi, il est fort à parier que seule la seconde tournure est juste. A savoir

> C’est drôle ***comme*** ces incidents se déroulent tous aujourd'hui !

ou

> C’est drôle ***à quel point*** ces incidents se déroulent tous aujourd'hui !

Sur un plan plus subjectif, sachez que la musicalité qui en découle est (susceptible d'être) dérangeante pour un francophone natif. Français, Québécois, Belges (et pardon pour les autres nationalités que je ne cite pas), qu'en pensez vous ?

Comment: La sonorité ne me dérange pas en tant que Français. La dernière édition de la question a rendu ma réponse 'décalée' par rapport a la version actuelle. La version précédente laissait un doute sur l'interprétation à suivre.